# identify a trigger of QAction

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qaction

below I quoted my code. The problem is easy to describe. selectedItem->text  is not the right way to differ what action was selected in the menu. How to do it right?

```
void RView::ShowContextMenu(const QPoint& pos) // this is a slot
{
// for most widgets
QPoint globalPos = statusWidget->mapToGlobal(pos);
// for QAbstractScrollArea and derived classes you would use:
// QPoint globalPos = myWidget->viewport()->mapToGlobal(pos);

QMenu myMenu;
myMenu.addAction("first");
myMenu.addAction("second");

QAction* selectedItem = myMenu.exec(globalPos);
if (selectedItem)
{ 
    if(selectedItem->text == "first")
     // do something 
    if(selectedItem->text == "second")
     // do other stuff
}
else
{
    // nothing was chosen
}
}
```

Comment: ***How to do it right?*** Most likely to use signals and slots. Connect your QAction triggered signal(s) to slots in your RView class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rather compare the `QAction`s directly and either use the comparison of `selectedItem` as you do in your `if`s or better yet connect each action to the desired slot (or lambda if they are one time things localised to this context).

```
QMenu myMenu;
QAction *action1 = myMenu.addAction("first");
QAction *action2 = myMenu.addAction("second");
connect(action1, &QAction::triggered, [](){/*lambda code here*/});
connect(action2, &QAction::triggered, [](){/*lambda code here*/});
myMenu.exec(statusWidget->mapToGlobal(pos));
```

EDIT: For Qt4 you would use slots and old connect syntax:

```
QMenu myMenu;
QAction *action1 = myMenu.addAction("first");
QAction *action2 = myMenu.addAction("second");
connect(action1, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(doStuff()));
connect(action2, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(doOtherStuff()));
myMenu.exec(statusWidget->mapToGlobal(pos));
```

For this to work you will need "doStuff" and "doOtherStuff" to be declared as slots in your header taking no arguments (becuase the signal `QAction::triggered()` have none). The code you want done will go to definitions of these slots:

```
class RView
{
public slots:
    void doStuff() { /*do stuff*/ }
    void doOtherStuff() { /*do other stuff*/ }
};
```

Comment: the compiler don't know triggered

Comment: Sorry, should have been QAction, not QObject. Corrected it. And the lambda code is whatever you need done when that action is triggered. The "//do something" and "//do other stuff" in OP.

Comment: Whatever you want executed when the action is triggered. To use a lambda for this assumes you are using some version of Qt5.

Comment: that's not good, now I have problems, because it is in lambda code.

Comment: and triggered is still unknown.

Comment: ***and triggered is still unknown.*** Do you need to know that? I mean you should have 1 action per menu item. Each action has its own lambda to execute code for that action.

Comment: okay, ist not triggered what is unkown... there is no function named connect with this arguments and triggerd is the problem.

Comment: Are you using Qt5? Maybe you need to include <QAction> If you are using Qt4 lambdas will not work.

Comment: I'm using QT4, and I can't change. But I guess there must be another way, to differ what has been clicked.

Comment: ***But I guess there must be another way, to differ what has been clicked.*** Yes, there is a different connect syntax and you can't use the lambda but you can use a slots in your RView class.

Comment: drescherjm, can you please write an example?

Comment: Maybe later this evening. I have company and I am going out soon.

Comment: @Michael Vlach, thank you!! but there is a copy paste error. Both connect functions react on action1 ;)

Comment: @tux007 Right :-) Fixed that and glad to be of service.

Comment: If you have fixed actions, use one slot for each. If the number of actions is dependent on a runtime value, use a `QSignalMapper` or store the reference value as `QAction::data()` and retrieve it in the slot

Comment: @Kevin Krammer, I hate to resurrect an old thread, but how do I retrieve the QAction's data in the slot?

Comment: Never mind: `QAction *action = qobject_cast<QAction *>(QObject::sender());`